# Cómo puedo eliminar caracteres especiales de un string en c++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char palabra[100];

    cout << "Ingresa una palabra: ";
    cin.getline(palabra, 100); //optienes la cadena completa del arreglo

    for (int i = 0; palabra[i] != 0; ++i)
        if (palabra[i] != 32)//32 codigo ascci de espacio           
            cout << palabra[i];
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Sólo puedo eliminar los espacios pero no sé cómo eliminar los carácteres especiales.

Comment: Caracteres especiales de qué tipo?

Comment: Como los paréntesis,  signos de exclamación y así.

Comment: Y cómo los eliminas actualmente?

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 char palabra[100];
 int x;
 cout << "Ingresa una palabra: ";
 cin.getline(palabra, 100);//optienes la cadena completa del arreglo

 for (int i = 0; palabra[i] != 0; ++i) {
  if (palabra[i] > 47 && palabra[i] < 123) {//32 significa espacio en codigo ascii!!    
    cout << palabra[i];
   cin.get();
  }
}
    return 0;
 }

Comment: Pero al imprimir,lo hace letra por letra

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente lo que haces es imprimir el `string` sin los caracteres deseados, desde mi perspectiva, tienes la siguiente posibilidad (que conste no es la única):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char CaracteresIndeseados[] = { '(', ')', ';', ' ', '.' };
    char Palabra[100]; int Switch = 0;
    cout << "Escribe la palabra: "; cin.getline(Palabra, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Palabra); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(CaracteresIndeseados); j++)
            if (Palabra[i] == CaracteresIndeseados[j]) Switch = 1;

        if (Switch == 0) cout << Palabra[i];
        Switch = 0;
    }
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Explicando, lo primero que hacemos es crear un `Array` donde almacenamos los caracteres que queremos eliminar, por ejemplo, parentesis y demás signos de puntuación.

Creamos una variable `int` para saber si el caracter actual debe ser impreso en pantalla, este es llamado `Switch`, si su valor es `0`, entonces debe imprimirse en pantalla, luego vuelve a su estado actual.

Primero se comprueba que para cada caracter dentro de la palabra escrita, se compare con todos los elementos de `CaracteresIndeseados`, si el resultado es igual, entonces se vá a saltar la impression de los caracteres.

Lo he probado con los siguientes strings:

```
"hola mundo"
"(soy un parentesis)"
"tengo;semicolon"
```

El resultado es, respectivamente:

```
holamundo
soyunparentesis
tengosemicolon
```

Dado que he puesto los espacios dentro de los caracteres indeseados.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Te paso un ejemplo donde uso una función que devuelve una string con los caracteres que se consideran alfabéticos (en el locale por defecto), sin modificar la string original.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>
#include <iterator>

std::string soloLetras(const std::string& str)
{
    std::locale loc(""); 

    std::string res;
    std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(res),
        [&loc](char c) { return std::isalpha(c, loc); });
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::string palabras = "deseo eliminar los caracteres que no sean letras, "
        "por ejemplo: números (1, 2, 3), o "
        "signos de puntuación (, ; ? ¿ ¡ ...)";


    std::cout << soloLetras(palabras) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

considero que la forma mas sencilla de hacerlo es usando varios `if` los cuales limiten los caracteres, para que solo se imprima las letras y los numeros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char palabra[100];

    cout << "Ingresa una palabra: ";
    cin.getline(palabra, 100); //optienes la cadena completa del arreglo

    for (int i = 0; palabra[i] != 0; ++i){
        if (palabra[i] <= 122 && palabra[i] >= 65){//para las letras
            if (palabra[i] < 91 || palabra[i] > 96){//para descartar los caracteres [ \ ] ^ _ `
                    cout << palabra[i];
            }
        }

        else if (palabra[i] <= 57 && palabra[i] >= 48) //para imprimir los numeros
                cout <<palabra[i];

    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

nota :compara los numeros con el codigo ASCII para que veas cuales he omitido